# Camel best practice, messages and exception handling

Tags: exception, jms, apache-camel

My problem, shortly:

I have to write the system, what publish data by ServiceMix. The target endpoints are Web services. That is the real possibility, one or more of then stopped. 
The business process requires the correct order of messages. 
Because of every system has one dedicated queue, what contains the messages. The target web services has been called by a dedicated route, where the defining of endpoint happens by a dynamic router.
It works correctly, if no error, but...
If the publication doesn't success, then the messages landing in DLQ.
I understand the logic of it, but I think this problem is not only mine. 
I want to leave the message in original queue, same position as the message arrived. I can stop the queue processor route, and I can restart it. This enough the handling of the output errors.

My question, How should I meet business expectations, without manual action? (manual means AcitveMQ console) 
All solution are interested. (I try the separate DLQ by systems, endless re delivery number, etc.,) 
If someone knows the solution, please share me.

Thank you!

Feri

Answer (score 0):

@Feri You need to use JMS message delivery with client acknowledgement i.e. if your route delivers successfully to the web-service then send a positive acknowledgement to the JMS broker else send negative. So, the message is marked as dequeued , only when it is being successfully delivered else it remains in the queue. Read more about message delivery in JMS refer

1. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074123/java-web-development/transaction-and-redelivery-in-jms.html
2. http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/01/jms-message-delivery-reliability-acknowledgement-patterns/

Comment: You are right!.But I have to do it in ServiceMix/Camel environment. And here I can't find such way, what can do it so. (Camel is comfortable, if you follow the "Camel-conform" path, but if not...! )

Comment: I am not sure about ServiceMix but it should not matter. You must be writing your camel routes in either Java or Spring DSL. See camel's (documentation)[http://camel.apache.org/jms.html] on setting the acknowledgment mode. For client ack you shall set the option, acknowledgementModeName to CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE on the consumer URI and after delivering the message, get the JMS message from exchange and invoke the acknowledge method.

Comment: I'l try what you suggest, but I think, this is a bit more complex. The callable WS is "InOnly", so I don't get ack. My problem not the WS answer handling, but the Camel exception handling. I can't set up the Camel route as I need. If some error happens on route processing, then the Camel doesn't leave message the original queue, everything take it to the Dead Letter Queue.